# javascript embedded function and embedded variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am writing a small app that will use the jQuery ajax call to make SOAP calls to a third party API.  I want to make the following function "generic" but am running into variable scoping issues in the innermost function in the "done()" ajax method.  That function is where the good stuff is returned.  I want the key, value pairs to be placed in the "result" object that is passed into the APICall function but i don't know how to reference it down there.

I don't think I can modify the function parameter list in the "done" section can I?  I just tried adding the passed in "result" to the "done" functions and there were no syntax issues but it is not working.

Ideas?

```
function APICall(method, username, password, payload, result) {
    var wsUrl = "https://localhost.my.company.org/API/Service.asmx";

    var soapRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
            + "<soap:Envelope \n"
            + "    soap:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
            + "    xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \n"
            + "    xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
            + "    xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"
            + "    xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"> \n"
            + "  <soap:Body> \n"
            + "    <__METHOD__ xmlns=\"http://THIRD-PARTY.API.Web.Service/\"> \n"
            + "      <UserName>__USERNAME__</UserName> \n"
            + "      <Password>__PASSWORD__</Password> \n"
            + "      __PAYLOAD__ \n" + "    </__METHOD__> \n"
            + "  </soap:Body> \n" + "</soap:Envelope>\n";

    soapRequest = soapRequest.replace(/__METHOD__/g, method);
    soapRequest = soapRequest.replace(/__USERNAME__/g, username);
    soapRequest = soapRequest.replace(/__PASSWORD__/g, password);
    soapRequest = soapRequest.replace(/__PAYLOAD__/g, payload);

    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            headers : {
                    SOAPAction : '"http://THIRD-PARTY.API.Web.Service/' + method + '"'
            },
            url : wsUrl,
            contentType : "text/xml",
            dataType : "xml",
            data : soapRequest,
            error : processAJAXError
     }).done(
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $($.parseXML($(data).find(method + 'Result').text())).find(
                            'Data').each(
                            function(key, val) {
                                result[$(val).find('Room').text()] = $(val).find(
                                        'ID').text();
                                    console.log($(val).find('Room').text() + ' => '
                                            + $(val).find('ID').text());
                            });
             });
}
```

Comment: Since AJAX is asynchronous, putting the KV pairs in the caller's `result` variable will do no good -- that function has already returned.

Comment: You should be able to access the `result` variable from within the done function but as Barmar said that likely won't help you.

Comment: Try to bind anonymous function with result .done( function(...){}.bind(result)); i don't know if you can also bind $.ajax.

Comment: Ah!, I see what you mean about the asynchronous behaviour.  My other code (Per) was making static requests.  I see that jQuery ajax has an `async=false` setting.  That might be best in this case.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try bind();

```
.done(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                  
        .
        .
        .

    }.bind(result));
```